# How can I tell whether sample size is inadequate or not ?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sampling

I am given sample size of 15322 students and our research topic is to find out a relationship between students academic performance and participation in sports team.

The question asks " do you think the sample size is adequate for our purpose?"

It seems like its very subjective question.

I don't know whether it is adequate or not.

Anybody has better ideas?

Comment: I would calculate its power under a two-sample Z-test of means. The likely answer is yes, that's a pretty good sized sample, so the means will be very nearly normally distributed for most measures of academic performance. But I agree...it sounds awfully subjective without more info.